# String Manipulation / Regex

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `NVARCHAR(MAX)` column which stores a log stream. What I need is to extract some values at the select statement level. As I cannot apply a regex without CLR, what would be the solution using some "string manipulation" functions?

For example, I might have this value in the `Log` column:

```
$CF_NONPROD_USERNAME -p $CF_NONPROD_PASSWORD -o $ORG -s $SPACE\u001B[0;m\nAPI endpoint: https://api.server02.pcf.com/\nAuthenticating...\nOK\n\nTargeted org Order-PSOrg\n\nTargeted space TEST4\n\n\n\nAPI endpoint:   https://api.server02.pcf.com (API version: 2.131.0)\nUser:           myuser@user.from.ldap.cf\nOrg:            Order-PSOrg\nSpace:          TEST4\n\u001B[32;1m$ $PRE_DEPLOY_CMD\u001B[0;m\n\"Deployment started\"\n\u001B[32;1m$ cf push $APP_NAME -p $TARGET -f $PCF_MF_FILE --no-start\u001B[0;m\nPushing f
```

I need to extract:

```
Targeted Org = *in this sample would be "Order-PSOrg"*

Targeted Space = *in this sample would be "TEST4"*

Api Endpoint = *in this sample would be "https://api.server02.pcf.com"*
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This query is seriously ugly, but does the job. Basically you retrieve the substring from the position of the key you are looking for ("Targeted Org", "Targeted Space" and "Api Endpoint") until the position of the following "\n" string. Finally you remove that key from the previous result.

Functions used :

1. **charindex** to get the position of a substring within a string
2. **substring** to get the substring betwen two positions
3. **replace** to remove the searched key from the previous result
4. **ltrim** and **rtrim** to remove blank spaces at the start and end

Query:

```
create table MyLogsTable (Log varchar(max))    
insert into MyLogsTable (Log) values ('$CF_NONPROD_USERNAME -p $CF_NONPROD_PASSWORD -o $ORG -s $SPACE\u001B[0;m\nAPI endpoint: https://api.server02.pcf.com/\nAuthenticating...\nOK\n\nTargeted org Order-PSOrg\n\nTargeted space TEST4\n\n\n\nAPI endpoint: https://api.server02.pcf.com (API version: 2.131.0)\nUser: myuser@user.from.ldap.cf\nOrg: Order-PSOrg\nSpace: TEST4\n\u001B[32;1m$ $PRE_DEPLOY_CMD\u001B[0;m\n\"Deployment started\"\n\u001B[32;1m$ cf push $APP_NAME -p $TARGET -f $PCF_MF_FILE --no-start\u001B[0;m\nPushing f')

select ltrim(rtrim(replace(substring(Log, charindex('Targeted Org', Log), charindex('\n', Log, charindex('Targeted Org', Log)) - charindex('Targeted Org', Log)), 'Targeted Org', ''))) as Target_Org,
       ltrim(rtrim(replace(substring(Log, charindex('Targeted Space', Log), charindex('\n', Log, charindex('Targeted Space', Log)) - charindex('Targeted Space', Log)), 'Targeted Space', ''))) as Target_Space,
       ltrim(rtrim(replace(substring(Log, charindex('Api Endpoint:', Log), charindex('\n', Log, charindex('Api Endpoint:', Log)) - charindex('Api Endpoint:', Log)), 'Api Endpoint:', ''))) as Api_Endpoint       
from MyLogsTable
```

[You can see it working at DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bf56cc77a830945c62d008cba2329c4f)